# Tooltip hover on selected field in angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

html code

```
<td >  
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="create.qty[i]"   (mouseenter)="toggle()" (mouseleave)="toggle()" name="qty"       [(ngModel)]="this.create.qty[i]" #qty="ngModel" (change)="onqtyadd($event.target.value,i)"  >
 <div *ngIf="show">
 <div  *ngIf="show" style="border-radius: 6px;z-index: 8;position: absolute; background-color:black;height: 15%;padding-left:10px;color:white; width: 5%;"><p>{{qtyhover[i]}}</p></div>
 </div>
</td>
```

I just want to show the selected field but it show hover in every field in dynamic table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm7wn.png)

Comment: can you show your toggle() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead use `boolean` property use `number` like `show:number`

and set an index (the current) to `show` on `mouseenter/leave` and in html ask if `show`==`index`

**in HTML:**

(you do not have to ask twice `ngIf` only in wrap `div`)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  (mouseenter)="show=i" (mouseleave)="show=0">
<div *ngIf="show==1">
  <div>your tooltip 1 </div>
</div>
```

See example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-eu5ecu?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: this.show==0?index:0; when I code in code this line in component.ts I am getting error

Comment: do as my example: `(mouseenter)="show=i" (mouseleave)="show=0"`  you do not have to use function

Comment: I tried but it still shows the data only in 2nd input field

Comment: I belive your `i` starts from 0 so use to first  `*ngIf="show==0"` and second `*ngIf="show==1"` and etc.

Comment: sir it's dynamic field and still the problem is same

Comment: use stackblitz--You have to put code fork and post link